# Ajax load is not working in chrome while its working in fire fox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

```
 $('.sband_level1 li').live('click',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();      
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: base_url+"product/update_products",
        data: "style_id="+style_list+'&prod_id='+brand_list+'&term_name='+term_name+'&term_id='+term_id,
        context: this,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
         $('.blocker_new').css('display','block')
        }, 
        success: function(msg){
         $('#page_wn').empty();
         $('#page_wn').append(msg);
         $('.blocker_new').removeAttr('style')
        }
       });
});
```

when I do click n FF my div is coming properly; that is blocker new div. While same thing is not working in chrome...that is blocker new div is not coming....my ajax is working properly...I am getting correct output..

Comment: It shows something on console?

Comment: Removing the "style" attribute is really the wrong way to change the style of an element.  Just set "display" back to "none".

Comment: no I am not getting any error in console.

Comment: @cnm1990 Are you running this page script locally? As in, are you using the `file:///path/to/your/htmlpage.html` protocol?

Comment: @cnm1990 http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677/1524085 read this

Comment: I am running this script on server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Chrome ignores requests to remove the "style" attribute of a DOM element.

```
     $('.blocker_new').css('display', 'none');
```

should work, or more simply

```
     $('.blocker_new').hide();
```

Comment: Hi Pointy, I tried both things 1)  $('.blocker_new').hide(); 2)$('.blocker_new').css('display','none'); 

But still the same issue I am facing.
when I comment $('.blocker_new').hide(); afer successful ajax call my div is getting load. so jus to display it is taking lot of time.

Comment: @cnm1990 well I'm not sure I understand exactly what is not working. I don't know what you mean by, "blocker_new is not coming".

Comment: Hi pointy, Sorry for the above reply..actually was in hurry so couldnt explain you properly.
I am trying to show loading text on click. This image is coming from the bloker_new div. so When I do click that text is not coming.same thing is Fire fox

Answer (score 0):

try moving your $('.blocker_new').hide(); to the complete callback

```
...
complete:function() {
$('.blocker_new').hide();
}
...
```